# Cannot input text with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to input password to the box with Selenium but it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: element not interactable`

My python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://creis.fang.com/'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('cnotp').send_keys('123456')
```

If I run the script, the above error appears. However, if I type line by line in the console. Then there is no error.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you wait a few milliseconds between each pair of commands (something like [`implicitly_wait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits))?

Comment: I added time.sleep(5) before and after `browser.get(url)`. But it has no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the **password** field using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://creis.fang.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.loginipt.fl#cnotp"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.loginipt.fl#cnpassword"))).send_keys("Chan")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://creis.fang.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='loginipt fl' and @id='cnotp']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='loginipt fl' and @id='cnpassword']"))).send_keys("Chan")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: password]

Comment: Thank you, DebanjanB. Why should we click first instead of directly input the text?

Comment: @Chan This was a one off case which I haven't seen before. In short, the developers have induced `display: none` on focus, so the you need to send text to the adjustment element.

Comment: DebanjanB, I tried to input text to the next field but failed.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='cntempcode']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(browser, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='cntempcode']"))).send_keys("0000")`

Comment: @Chan Observe the HTML properly and track the changes. I believe they have implemented the same logic for each element. If you are still unable, raise a new ticket, I will look into it once I reach home.

Comment: I solved the problem by directly executing `WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='cntempcode']"))).send_keys("0000")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to do it "by step". First select the element, clear its value then do the send_key stuff...

```py
element = browser.find_element_by_id('cnotp')
element.clear()
element.send_keys('123456')
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Oh, I checked the website and the field you're trying to fill seem to be a password field. There maybe is a protection on that specific field that won't let you interact that easily as the other fields would.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: I don't know but if the website blocks you using a JS script you have nothing to do. It could be some protection agaisnt bots. But I didn't check if it's true, it's just a supposition.

Answer (score 0):

Wailt always whenever there is a url change.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Change
driver.get('https://creis.fang.com/')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cnotp"))
)

element.clear()
element.send_keys("123456")
```

If it does not work, use js_executor

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "cnotp"))
)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('cnotp').click()")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '123456')", element);
```

Comment: I tried your method but still cannot input the text.